# ShimWarning on importing Shell form SimpleCV

Tags: python, python-2.7, simplecv

When I import Shell from SimpleCV

> from SimpleCV import Shell

I get this error

> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config.py:13: ShimWarning: The `IPython.config` package has been deprecated. You should import from traitlets.config instead.
>    "You should import from traitlets.config instead.", ShimWarning)
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\frontend.py:21: ShimWarning: The top->level `frontend` package has been deprecated. All its subpackages have been >moved to the top `IPython` level.
>    "All its subpackages have been moved to the top `IPython` level.", >ShimWarning)

Although on calling the

> Shell.main()

The SimpleCV console does start, however when I close the window for img.show(), it just quits the whole python console not just SimpleCV console

Don't know what is happening!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the SimpleCV code needs to be updated - I believe it was written for an older version than what gets installed. Here's what you need to do:

Find `Shell.py` which may be in somewhere like `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\SimpleCV\Shell` and open it in an editor. Then do the following

Around line 50 change `from IPython.config.loader import Config` to `from traitlets.config.loader import Config`

Around line 51, change `from IPython.frontend.terminal.embed import InteractiveShellEmbed` to `from IPython.terminal.embed import InteractiveShellEmbed`